# Integral raised to power p \leq integral where integrand is raised to power p.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, inequality, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

For any non-negative real-valued Lebesgue integrable function $ f $ on $ \mathbb{R}^n $, does the inequality
$$ \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f \: \mathrm{d}x \right)^p \leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} f^p \: \mathrm{d}x . $$
hold true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is false, as can be seen by testing against indicator functions $\chi_A$ of measurable sets.